# Advice on this method that works with chars

Tags: c#, arrays

Recently I've been told to change one validation towards a database to a new database in a C# application. Instead of the old database I would be using the new one.

The problem is that I can't run the app. I need to publish it so the guys that uses it give me their feedback.

So I decided to share this part of the code that I added.
Not changed, but added. This is something new and a potential thing that can go wrong.
Hopefully someone with more experience will tell me how much my code sucks or if it looks OK.

Thing is... the old database has an `int` value in a column and the new one has a `nvarchar(5)`.

So I made this to convert the old one in a new one.

```
string ConvertIDToReg(string kairosID)
    {
        double n;

        if (!Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(kairosID),
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
                System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out n))
                {
                    return "0";
                }

        char[] regID = kairosID.ToCharArray();

        if (regID.Length > 4)
        {
            return "0";
        }

        if (reg.Length == 3)
        {
            regID[4] = regID[3];
            regID[3] = regID[2];
            regID[2] = regID[1];
            regID[1] = regID[0];
            regID[0] = "0";
        }

        return regID.ToString();
    }
```

This is how it should work:

The old ID is something like "1234" but the new one is a 5 char max ID with a 0 in the beginning like "01234" (if the 5th number is not occupied). So basically I want to be able to put a 0 in the beginning if there isn't a 5th number.

If the number exceeds the 5 digits I want to return a 0 as the whole string (this will be handled later)

If the number is not a number (i.e "123ABC") return a 0 all the same.

Should this compile or even work?

What about efficiency? This will run several times. Any help to make this faster will do.

Comment: `Should this compile or even work?` I'm not sure, you should be able to tell us if you made it heh

Comment: So you want to convert a number to a string of exactly 5 digits if it fits, and "0" if it doesn't? That's it? `string sID = oldID >= 100000 ? "0" : oldID.ToString("00000");`

Comment: shouldn't the logic to do this be applied before the int value is converted to a string?  Less parsing and converting that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this won't compile.  You misspelled your second `regID` (forgot the 'ID'), and are assigning a string to a char at `regID[0] = "0";`

Change that and it will compile, then blow up when you run it, when `regID.Length=  3`, because you're trying to access index `3` and `4`, which it clearly will not have.

This should do what you're wanting:

```
string ConvertIDToReg(string kairosID)
{
    if (kairosID.Length > 4 || kairosID.Any(c => !char.IsDigit(c)))
         return "0";

    return kairosID.PadLeft(5, '0');
}
```

if it's longer than 4 characters or if any character is not a digit, return a zero as a string (`"0"`).  Else return the ID padded to 5 digits.  About as simple as i can make it I think.  No need to parse it as an int even.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
 private string ConvertIntToChar(string numValue)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(numValue, out result) == false || numValue.Length > 4)
            {
                return "0";
            }

            return numValue.PadLeft(5, '0');
        }
```

If value is not of 4 characters then it will add number of "0" required to make the string length equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always some form of an integer i would approach the problem as such. and you wanted to keep every thing else the same. the "D5" tells the ToString method to 0 pad the string so that it is always 5 digits but retains the same numerical value.

```
string ConvertIDToReg(string kairosID)
    {
        int id;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(kairosID, out id) || id > 9999)
        {
            return "0";
        }
        return id.ToString("D5");
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (!Int32.TryParse(kairosID, out id)) || id.ToString().Length > 4)` ?  OP wants "0" to return if length of the parsed id is greater than 4.

Comment: my recommendation was to test the length on the parsed id (convert to string first), in case white space was somehow injected into the `kairosID` parameter. E.g., it may start as `  098  `, which is 7 chars, but the int parsed will be 3 chars in length.